# how to call $scope.function1 from $scope.function2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller with the two functions.function "fileHistory" will be loaded first.

and i need to same call the same function from another function success callback.

i tried this way- but i am getting error
here is my Controller code

```
function cBookController($scope,$http) {

    $scope.fileHistory = function() {   
        $http({
            url: '/123/rest/getUploadDetails',
            method: "GET"
        })
        .success(function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.fileHistory = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Error in get history details process");
        });
    }

    $scope.fileHistory();

    $scope.checkStatus = function(uploadedFileId) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/123/rest/checkStatus',           
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        //here i need to get the new datafrom fileHistory service.
                        $scope.fileHistory();
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking in your code I see that inside the $http success callback of fileHistory function, you override your function with response data from $http

Answer (score 0):

Your `fileHistory` is a function at first. But after your promise is executed you are assigning this to a `data` variable and overriding it.

Change following line to something else -

```
 //$scope.fileHistory = data; // change this line 
 $scope.fileHistoryData = data;
```